# Scala Case Class with Different Argument Types

Tags: scala

I want to write a case class that can take in a function that has one or more Ints as its arguments. For instance, these would be valid functions:

```
def foo(x: Int): String = "foo"
def bar(x: Int, y: Int): String = "bar"
def foobar(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): String = "foobar"
```

but this would not:

```
def nonExample():String = "no"
```

The problem is that I can't get the right argument type for my case class.

```
case class Mine(function: ???) {}
```

I've tried:

```
case class Mine(function: (Int*) => String)
```

and this didn't work since (`Int*`) is a sequence of `Ints`. I also tried using Function and Function1, but that didn't work either. Any ideas (or alternatives if this isn't possible in Scala)?

***Edit:*** As Didier Dupont mentioned, `Mine` also needs to know how many arguments the method requires. Above I oversimplified `Mine`. It will also take another argument that tells about the function passed in. Based on that, it'll decide how many parameters to pass into the function. But other than that chunk of code, everything else in `Mine` operates the same regardless of the function.

Comment: My first thought is this isn't possible, but Scala always surprises me. :)

Comment: `Function1`, `Function2`, etc.. don't share a useful common trait, so I have serious doubts about it working without some magic.

Comment: Btw, methods can not be passed around, functions can.

Comment: How do you intend to use class Mine then? As you will not know how many arguments the method requires, it will be difficult to call it.

Comment: case classes are generally meant to be value containers more than anything really, a perfect example is the `Either` type. It has `Left` and `Right` as its possible values, each only supposed to hold a single value. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to pattern match against something that has multiple one-parameter versions of itself, as it all ends up looking the same after erasure

Comment: @ccheneson: Thanks. I'll edit it from method to function.

Comment: why is this sort of magic necessary? can't it be solved more cleanly by redesigning some other parts of the program?

Comment: @ErikAllik: My only other solution is to break this into a lot of different case classes, each specialized to deal with one type of function. I was just wondering if this could be done all with one case class in Scala. If it turns out this isn't actually possible, I'll go back and work around it.

Comment: yes, but why do you have so many different functions when they could all take `Seq[Int]` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recomend next solution (it has some disadvantages, but generaly it satisfy your needs)

```
sealed trait FuncRes[F] {
  def resolve : F
}

object FuncRes {
  implicit def func1[T1, R](f : T1 => R) = 
    new FuncRes[(T1 => R)] {
      def resolve = f
    }

  implicit def func2[T1, T2, R](f : (T1, T2) => R) =
    new FuncRes[((T1, T2) => R)] {
      def resolve = f
    }

  implicit def func3[T1, T2, T3, R](f : (T1, T2, T3) => R) = 
    new FuncRes[((T1, T2, T3) => R)] {
      def resolve = f
    }
}

case class Mine[F](private val f : FuncRes[F]) {
  def func[F] = f.resolve
}
```

and usage example:

```
def foo(x: Int): String = "foo"
def bar(x: Int, y: Int): String = "bar"
def foobar(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): String = "foobar"

val m1 = Mine(foo _)
println { m1.func(10) }              // output: "foo"

val m2 = Mine(bar _)
println { m2.func(10, 20) }          // output: "bar"

val m3 = Mine(foobar _) 
println { m3.func(10, 20, 30) }     // output: "foobar"
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, Yury. Note to anyone else interested: With FuncRes, this is how you would actually pass foo, bar, and foobar into Mine: val m1 = Mine(FuncRes.func1(foo)), and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

How about `(Int, Int*) => String`? You would receive the second argument as a `Seq[Int]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I tried it in the repl and for foo, bar, and foobar there were all type mismatches.

Answer (score -1):

Why not using a function `Array[Int] => String`? Varargs are essentially array so it should fit.